# Figures and tables do not fit on page

Tags: floats, positioning, elsarticle

I am using the `elsarticle` class and the standard template provided by them (see below). My problem is that all the figures are being put on the last page of my paper all tables are not being shrinked. Is there a way I could make LaTeX put the figures anywhere else except the last page and also reduce the size of the tables (something like `scale=0.3*linewidth`)?

```
\documentclass[preprint,5p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\journal{x}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{x}
\author{x}
\ead{X}
\author{x}
\ead{x}
\address{x}

\begin{abstract}
The best abstract ever!!!\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
a;
b;
c;
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
\label{Sec-Introduction}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: John, I assume you mean `scale=0.3*\linewidth`. If so, expect to get an error: scale is a number between 0 and 1, whereas \linewidth is a length (number + unit).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are writing a paper for Elsevier, hence your choice of the `elsarticle` class.
On that basis, I suspect they have a good reason for wanting the figures at the end and unless there is something in the documentation, they will stay at the end.

What do you mean by shrinking tables?
As far as I am aware, the only solution to tables that are too wide is to hardcode the width of entries, but maybe I am wrong.